# Render panel when (datagrid)arraylist is empty

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Hi I am using p:layout component.

```
p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;" id="layout">  
    <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="100" minSize="40" maxSize="200">  

        <p:panel id="pnl" header="Help" toggleable="true"  toggleSpeed="500" 
        closeSpeed="500" widgetVar="panel" style="width:265px" rendered="#{backBean.renderPanel}">  
</p:panel>
<p:dataGrid var="sample" value="#{backBean.list}"
                            columns="1" style="margin-left: -5px;width: 275px; border:none;"
                            rows="7" >

                            //displaying some values from list here

</p:dataGrid>
        <p:poll interval="3"   
            listener="#{backBean.check}" update="pnl" />  
    </p:layoutUnit>  

    <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
        Center  
    </p:layoutUnit>
```

> Now I want to render panel as shown above when list is empty,if its
>   empty then panel will not get rendered.       So I as we know we have
>   p:poll component which automaticallly updates any particular panel or
>   any else component after specified    interval.   So I have applied poll
>   listener and checking list size in this way.

```
public void check(){

    if(list.size>0){
    renderPanel=false;
    }
    else{
    renderPanel=true;
    }
    }
which is working fine . I am getting value of renderPanel flag as true when list is empty , but still my panel is not rendering.
why is it so? what I am missing?

My backing bean code for renderPanel flag :



@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
    class BackBean implements Serializable{

    private  boolean renderPanel=false;
        public boolean isRenderPanel() {
        return renderPanel;
    }


    public void setRenderPanel(boolean renderPanel) {
        this.renderPanel = renderPanel;
    }



    }
```

> How should I render my panel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the parent of your panel since it can't be re-rendered when it is not existing in the first time :

```
<h:panelGroup id="pnl">
    <p:panel header="Help" toggleable="true"  toggleSpeed="500" closeSpeed="500" widgetVar="panel" style="width:265px" rendered="#{backBean.renderPanel}">  
    </p:panel>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Now the **pnl** will always exists no mather the `rendered="#{}"` attribute of it's child.